# Unable to get client IP address in Express even after setting 'trust proxy' to true

Tags: express, nginx, next.js

How do I retrieve the browser's IP address in a NextJS app? Right now, my custom [server](https://github.com/amitschandillia/proost/blob/master/web/server/server.js) has the following entries:

```
const server = express();
server.set('trust proxy', true);
```

Then in my [_app.js](https://github.com/amitschandillia/proost/blob/master/web/pages/_app.jsx):

```
const ip = ctx.req.header('x-forwarded-for') || ctx.req.connection.remoteAddress;
      console.log('IP ADDRESS', ip);
```

This whole thing is running behind an [NGINX proxy](https://github.com/amitschandillia/proost/blob/master/.documentation/configs/default.conf) which has the following directives:

```
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

Is there anything else that I'm missing out on? Because despite all this, I keep getting the localhost IP (127.0.0.1) in the console!

**UPDATE**: I tried `console.log('IP', ctx.req.ip);` and even that returned the same IP: `::ffff:127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it is working perfectly.

```
console.log(req.ip)
```

Comment: Do you have the same proxy configs as I do? And the entry `server.set('trust proxy', true);` in your server file?

Comment: Wait I am checking then inform you.

Comment: app.set('trust proxy', true);

Comment: var express = require("express"); var app = express(); app.set('trust proxy', true); console.log(req.ip);    output is - ::ffff:10.1.4.153

Comment: Yes, my frontend (React) and backend (Node/Nginx) codebase is on the same server. But the frontend code (React) still runs in the browser, right? I need to retrieve the IP address of the browser. Am sure this is a common use-case.

Comment: If you deploy your code on server you will get the same IP address, If you deploy both projects on different servers then you will get different IP and if you want to differentiate anything you can find the port.

Comment: How will deploying on different servers give me the IP address of the client's browser?

Comment: Console.log(req)   print complete req and analysis you will find everything port ip client ip.